# Is Usage a noun or a verb?

Tags: discussion

This is a site for English Language *Usage*. To me, usage implies use, which implies an active, present-time focus, including improvements that can be made. Why study usage at all unless your goal is to improve, not only yourself, but the field?

So I often wonder why questions like [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324583/what-is-a-better-term-than-unleaded-gasoline?) that propose improvements to usage are always met with the answer: "because we have always done it that way"? Isn't that antithetical to the very concept of usage as an evolving, improving practice in everyday life? Eschew Ossification!

Comment: I think you should make your question more clear. You are trying to argue that questions that propose a change in usage of English words and terms should be on topic here. The rhetorical devices used in your question do not help to get the message across. I would advise you to edit your question, making it more clear.

Comment: It's a noun, like "progress" and "improvement," not a verb, like "stagnate" and "ossify." Just saying, you might not want to use inaccurate grammatical metaphors like "verbs are inherently dynamic, nouns are inherently static" on a site full of grammar pedants. It distracts from your actual point.

Comment: I think the vast majority of motorists who pull up at a gas/petrol station simply ask the attendant to fill their car with gas/petrol/super/diesel. Maybe 20 years ago you had to specify between leaded (normal) and unleaded (I think the term "green" was also used but I'm not very sure) but the petrol companies are probably obliged by law to label their petrol unleaded when it actually *is*. Can you imagine what would happen if companies suddenly said "Hey folks, from now on we're going to stop writing *unleaded* because it is redundant" I'd be the first not to trust any Italian-run oil company.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ask someone? I have not seen anything but self-serv for a long time. Why would people pay extra to have someone else pump it when they are perfectly capable themselves?

Comment: Well, petrol/gas attendants still exist in Italy, and I still see motorists who don't get out of their cars. My point was that "we" already say petrol/gas in everyday speech, the fact that oil companies still label their products "unleaded" must have a deeper legal motive. I suspect Rathony's answer supplies that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [linked to](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/324583/2) a question whose title asks for a *better term* in the context of established usage. The question's elaboration proposes using a generic term (e.g. *regular*) to replace one that is more specific (e.g. *unleaded*).

There are a couple of issues here.

- A "Should we call this something else?" question in this context is arguably classifiable as *naming* and hence off-topic at ELU.
- Replacing what amounts to specialist terminology that has well-defined meaning (*unleaded*) with a generic term (*standard* or *regular*) can easily lead to 'misunderstandings'. E.g. Driver: "I used your fuel and now my car won't go." Fuel attendant: "Well, *our* 'standard fuel' is diesel. You should have used the 'non-standard fuel', or *unleaded* as they used to call it."

Wording the question differently can help, e.g. "What is a positive term (not *un*-something) for *unleaded* petrol?" This better fits the purpose of ELU because it is something for which an ordinary individual's answer can be authoritative, as opposed to something that requires either the relevant authorities or mass participation to be effective.

Based on my reading of your meta question, your main issue is about

> an active, present-time focus, including improvements that can be made.

Consider programming as an analogy to the use of English: we use programming languages and standard libraries to build new and innovative programs. Even the languages and libraries themselves change over time. Consider:

- What you are asking in your linked question is something akin to "Should we rename the *for-loop* to the *standard* or *regular* programming construct since *for* isn't a good word for expressing iteration?"
- A good understanding of the 'language and libraries' or 'English as currently used' paves the way for innovation. There is a place for a repository of current usage, even if your goal is innovation.

Comment: Thank you. The more general vs more specific issue is one that is important to me. It is related to but not the same as usual vs specialized. So in the Diesel example, far fewer vehicles use diesel than gasoline, so it is specialized. Gasoline would be the default, or 'unmarked' choice, the one most people would use. I am not in favor of having to add words to the usual, like having to specify coffee that is not decaf. If I want something special, I should have to ask for it specially, otherwise I get the usual. In the For Loop example, if it is the most common, I would just call it a "loop".

Comment: @nocomprende You're welcome. The point about diesel's popularity is illustrative - it depends on [where you are](http://www.acea.be/statistics/tag/category/passenger-car-fleet-by-fuel-type). E.g. in France and Spain, diesel is more popular than petrol according to the linked stats. Granted that you might not be conversing in English there, but the point holds: in this context, 'default' is *relative*. If you're particular about what you want, an *absolute* term is safer.

Comment: I think we have enough experience with things being different in formerly separated areas that now communicate to know that it does not work. We have to choose terms that work everywhere, for everyone and over foreseeable time. Technical standards are similar: the stupidity of 220 V 50 Hz vs 110 V 60 Hz could have been avoided. Even worse the craziness of driving on different sides of the road. Such problems only get worse with time. They are best avoided.

Comment: @nocomprende Indeed. But that needs to be tackled at the systemic level. Calling one particular system 'standard' doesn't address the underlying differences.

Comment: So rather than standard, simply use the name of the product: gasoline. Perhaps all relative terms are best avoided. I started a new question to this effect.

Comment: @nocomprende Sounds like an improvement :) . That's a better way of phrasing what I think you've been getting at all along, which, if I may, I'll paraphrase as "Call a spade (just) a spade, unless you really want a shovel or spatula; don't call it a *shovel spade* even if that's what people are used to calling it."

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of different issues here:

- 'Usage' is a noun (but somehow I think by asking that there is something deeper. You probably want to be more clear to get a relevant answer.
- Questions are closed for many reasons and even the stated reasons are not so literal or consistent or applicable to a given situation (even when obviously closable). You question is closable for many reasons: it is asking for opinions (the established norm here is for factual answers; it doesn't present the situation well (few examples) meaning not enough research has been presented (the varieties and histories of words used).
- Prescriptivism vs Descriptivism - You are under the misapprehension that this site is intended for setting language policy in English. Answers on ELU lean toward descriptivism but also try to explain what the standard is. ELU is not a school teacher or newspaper editor but it is also not a half-educated teenager (even though sometimes it feels that way).
- Language history - Language isn't the labels in a database schema. Language just doesn't change that way. Language isn't literal, isn't logical, and it can't easily be forced. Things change as they will or won't change as they will. You may suggest a change, but there are better ways than peeving about it.

In the end, I don't think you made a good case for the suggested change. Chat is probably a better place to have an informed discussion (though don't expect much coherence there).

Comment: I guess I see no point in studying something except to improve it. We are always told how English is changing over time, but I suppose it is something that just happens to us, because we cannot seem to think *about* language, it thinks us instead? Not very appealing.

Comment: Sure, that is a great attitude, especially for an engineer. Science is more about discovering rather than forcing.

Comment: I AM an engineer. Also a Hetaira (personality type). Not a bad combination. I guess I see no point in discovering if some forcing is not going to follow. I mean, why did the ancient Greeks figure out that the moon is a ball going around the (round) Earth and the Sun is a star, if no one was going to make productive use of that information for 2500 years? That is being a dilettante, not a scientist. As Robert Pirsig said, Knowledge is not so much *true* as *useful*. So, use away! Let's make some straight roads, much though the crooked roads are charming.

Answer (score 2):

I realise "answer the question" perhaps doesn't apply here but, a noun.

Comment: So, you are saying, **usage is what is, not what could or should be**? I find that unbelievably pessimistic and uninspiring. What sort of repository does not aim to provide for improvement? Why record the past when we can make the present better?

Comment: maybe you're trolling but no, I'm saying "usage" is a noun, not a verb.. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/usage

Comment: I guess urging improvement is trolling. I give up.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that one person's "improvement" is another person's "corruption." This site is for asking questions that have reasonably objective answers, or "good subjective" answers as described in the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) (basically, these are answers to "why" or "how" questions). It's not a place for proposing changes to usage. People can't really "answer" such proposals, only "respond" to them by giving their opinions.

Comment: This. An "active, present-time focus" on the Use of English does not include speculative assertions on how it might be "improved" for the future.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask a question about "word usage", you should make some efforts to do your own research and show us what you found and what still bothers you.

> [Search and
>   research](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Have you
>   thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing
>   your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t
>   meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try
>   to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and
>   above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

What makes you think proposing to use "standard" or "regular" in place of "unleaded" is improving anything? I think your question comes from your misunderstanding of the term "unleaded" and how it has been used historically. See this link, [The U.S. Experience with the Phasedown
of Lead in Gasoline](http://web.mit.edu/ckolstad/www/Newell.pdf).

In addition, the adjective "regular" is used before gasoline to differentiate other *octane grades such as "premium"* and it has nothing to do with whether gasoline is leaded or unleaded.

A [simple research](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0210-paying-premium-high-octane-gasoline) would have answered your question and explain why we can't use "regular" or "standard" for "unleaded".

Answer to your question on the main site, what is a better term than "unleaded" gasoline?

> There is no better term than "unleaded" and "regular" or "standard" can never be used
>   to mean "unleaded" as they have another specific usage.

Comment: Well,I am feeling rather unenlightened by all of this. But I suppose there is no better way of putting it.